# Configure Redmine into linux shared hosting server

Tags: git, redmine

Hi i have installed redmine in my local system but now i need to install redmine in my linux hosting server.. how can i do this..? is't possible to move local file to remote server and configure or need to install in remote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to spend your time copying the files over and configuring Redmine for the server. But it is most likely worth your time to simply install Redmine on the server side. That way you don't find yourself trying to change all the config files for the server file system.

Good luck!